# floats (figures...) does not respect width of adjustwidth

Tags: floats, adjustwidth

When I use floats in the middle of an environment that uses `adjustwidth`, the caption takes the whole space instead of simply taking the space allowed by adjust width. The problem is that I want to draw lines in the margin obtained with `adjustwidth`, and lines overlap with the content:

[image]

Is there a way to make sure that my captions will behave correctly (I'm fine with getting rid of adjustwidth if you have a better solution that works with floats)?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[options]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{thmtools} %% Improves existing theorem packages (like amsthm) and provides declaretheorem
\theoremstyle{plain} % Style, see http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf p. 8 for recommanded styles
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
  \advance\textwidth-2cm% Hum... Is it safe to do that?
  \advance\linewidth-2cm
  \lipsum[2][1-3]

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}\\
    See I don't care about adjustwidth
    \caption{\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    \label{fig:fds}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[2][1-3]
\end{adjustwidth}


\end{document}
```

For the captions, I found a funny trick: `\captionsetup`. I'm not sure if it's the best solution... but does the job. But unfortunately, it does not apply to all floats. For instance, it does not apply to floats defined with the `float` environment.

If you have a better solution (that may work for more kinds of floats), please let me know. Also, if you know how to center the image, I'd be interested.

[image]

```
\documentclass[options]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{thmtools} %% Improves existing theorem packages (like amsthm) and provides declaretheorem
\theoremstyle{plain} % Style, see http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf p. 8 for recommanded styles
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\usepackage{caption}
%% Hyperref should be loaded before cryptocode! Otherwise, errors with labels of lines for example.
%%% Cryptocode
\usepackage [
  lambda,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
  ] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled} % Defines the "rule" style for next environments defined using newfloat.
\newfloat{protocol}{htb!}{protocol}
\floatname{protocol}{Protocol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
  \advance\textwidth-2cm% Hum... Is it safe to do that?
  \advance\linewidth-2cm%
  \captionsetup{width=\linewidth} % The width seems actually smaller than linewidth, but it does the trick.
  \lipsum[2][1-3]

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}\\
    See I don't care about adjustwidth
    \caption{\lipsum[3][1-3]}
    \label{fig:fds}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[2][1-3]
  \begin{protocol}
    \caption{My caption}
    \lipsum[1][1]
  \end{protocol}

  \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{adjustwidth}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

by adding `\advance\columnwidth-2cm` I managed also to change the size of floats inserted using the `float` library... Unfortunately it is still not perfect because the floats are flushed left, so the overlap is the same, and pictures are even less centered now ^^

[image]

**EDIT**

I tried to apply the advice of John to insert adjustwidth inside the floats. I semi-works for picture (the caption is still not behaving properly, either it is too big, or if I use `\captionsetup{width=1\linewidth}` it is too small), but fails with other floats:

[image]

```
\documentclass[options]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{thmtools} %% Improves existing theorem packages (like amsthm) and provides declaretheorem
\theoremstyle{plain} % Style, see http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf p. 8 for recommanded styles
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\usepackage{caption}
%% Hyperref should be loaded before cryptocode! Otherwise, errors with labels of lines for example.
%%% Cryptocode
\usepackage [
  lambda,
  advantage,
  operators,
  sets,
  adversary,
  landau,
  probability,
  notions,
  logic,
  ff,
  mm,
  primitives,
  events,
  complexity,
  asymptotics,
  keys
  ] {cryptocode}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled} % Defines the "rule" style for next environments defined using newfloat.
\newfloat{protocol}{htb!}{protocol}
\floatname{protocol}{Protocol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
  \advance\textwidth-2cm% Hum... Is it safe to do that?
  \advance\linewidth-2cm%
  \captionsetup{width=1\linewidth} % The width seems actually smaller than linewidth, but it does the trick.
  \lipsum[2][1-3]

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}
  \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
      %\advance\textwidth-2cm% Hum... Is it safe to do that?
      %\advance\linewidth-2cm%
      %\captionsetup{width=\linewidth} % The width seems actually smaller than linewidth, but it does the trick.
      \centering
      \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{2mm}\\
      See I don't care about adjustwidth
      \caption{\lipsum[3][1-3]}
      \label{fig:fds}
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{figure}
  \lipsum[2][1-3]
  \begin{protocol}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
      \caption{My caption}
      \lipsum[1][1]
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{protocol}

  \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{adjustwidth}


\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to comments of David on minipages I tried to create one inside figures... and indeed it basically solves the problem for pictures (now I need to automatically applies that), and it can actually float on new pages if required. I still need to find a way to patch all figure environments into my adjustwidth, but it's getting there. However, I'm not sure how to apply it to other kinds of floats, if I do that into a ruled environment the patch is not applied to the caption.

[image]

```
\documentclass[options]{memoir}

\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,tikzmark}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{thmtools} %% Improves existing theorem packages (like amsthm) and provides declaretheorem
\theoremstyle{plain} % Style, see http://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amscls/amsthdoc.pdf p. 8 for recommanded styles
\declaretheorem[name=Theorem,numberwithin=section]{theorem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled} % Defines the "rule" style for next environments defined using newfloat.
\newfloat{protocol}{htb!}{protocol}
\floatname{protocol}{Protocol}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
  \advance\textwidth-2cm% Hum... Is it safe to do that?
  %\advance\columnwidth-2cm% Hum... it's breaking images
  %\captionsetup{width=1\linewidth} % The width seems actually smaller than linewidth, but it does the trick.
  \lipsum[2][1-3]. Checking that linewidth and textwidth are appropriately configured

  \noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1mm}

  \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{1mm}

  \lipsum[2][1-3]

  \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
      \noindent\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{I am a true float, with the appropriate margin!! Now I need to patch all figure environments automatically.}
      \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{figure}

  Unfortunately, floats created with the float package are still not patched.
  \begin{protocol}
    \begin{adjustwidth}{2cm}{0cm}
      \noindent\begin{minipage}{1.0\linewidth}
      \caption{Non patched float}
      The adjustwidth is applied to the content of the float but not the the surounding. I need to find a way to apply this patch directly around the float.
      \end{minipage}
    \end{adjustwidth}
  \end{protocol}

  \lipsum[1][1-2]
\end{adjustwidth}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Adjustwidth does not actually change \textwicth, it just changes \leftskip and \rightskip to overlap the margins.  Floats  reset \leftskip and \rightskip to 0pt.  You could try putting \adjustwidth inside a float, which will work regardless of outside conditions.

Comment: you would see the same with a list such as itemize. the only reason to use a float is to mark its content as an insert not tied to that spot so by design it avoids picking up the local context

Comment: what do you want to happen if a float from before or after the adjustwidth floats into that block, or what do you want to happen if a float whose source in that block is typeset out of it?

Comment: @JohnKormylo thanks a lot for the precision. So I tried your solution using adjustwidth inside floats, and/or to change leftskip and rightskip at the beginning of the float environment, it helps for figure (even if caption is still broken), but not for other floats.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. I understand that it makes sense in the general setting, now my how setting is a bit particular ^^ So concerning the behavior I'd like, so far anything that looks nice when the bar will be drawn, with the fewest possible change for the final user :-D (I'd like to avoid to manually change all figures, I'd prefer a way to patch all of them at the same time) So far, my lines are drawn starting from the top of the text content (when a new page is created), so any float pushed inside my adjustwidth should be squeezed.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The other solution that may work for floats around the adjustwidth pushed inside would be maybe to start the line after the top/bottom floats are drawn, but then I've no idea in which function I need to hook into (if you have some ideas). But in any case I also need to find a fix for floats that are positioned "here", and this won't fix that.

Comment: if you want a captioned non-float I'd use `\captionof{figure}{whatever}`  in a minipage of width `\linewidth` (which will be affected by lists and adjustwidth etc)

Comment: there is no direct way to modify the width of a float that floats into or out of the region, you would have to save the page and position number and then compare with the tikzmarks for your lines and fix up the width on a later run

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I actually care about floats. However, your comment on minipage made me try to put the margin directly inside the image... and indeed it works, and it is a float! Now, I need to find a way to apply the same to other floats environments, like the ruled ones.

Comment: Concerning your idea about saving page and position number, and comparing them with my tikzmarks, it's a good idea (I guess I can use `\zlabel{bar} \zref[abspage]{bar}` for instance to get the page number, or maybe directly use tikzmark exists on page functions),  but I still need to find a way to patch all kinds of floats.